Handling Concurrency with RabbitMQ - MassTransit
For a project I am working on, I would like to set up the following architecture, but I am having some trouble finding what I need by reading documentation and searching on Google.
Basically, I have two .NET Core Web APIs: one acts as a producer (gateway), and the other as a consumer.
The request flow is

User post a request to a Gateway endpoint.
Gateway handle the request, perform some preliminary check
Gateway push the request into an exchange.
Consumer WebApi dequeue and process the Request

Now, since I have to handle a concurrency issue, I could dequeue the requests sequentially (one after the other), but this is not necessary because concurrency only needs to be managed within the context of the same RequestId.
Th Request message format is
public class RequestMessage {
   public Guid RequestId {get;set;}
   public Guid UserId {get;set;}
}

If I could set up the architecture so that messages with the same RequestId are processed one by one, that would solve the problem.
I can't define a fixed number of queues, so routing messages to different queues won't work in this case because the RequestId set is unknown.
One approach could be to create N queues and route messages to one of them using a function like f(RequestId) -> { one of N queues }, then process each queue sequentially. However, how can I create N instances of the same consumer to handle this?
I also need to ensure support for horizontal scaling, such as deploying additional instances of the consumer Web API.
I know there are RabbitMQ plugins like consistent hashing or sharding, and I see that the MassTransit library provides a UsePartition method. However, I am having trouble understanding how to properly set them up.documentation is really poor.
I write here the consumer webapi code for reference ...
// ... elided
return services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.AddConsumer<MessageRequestConsumer>(); 
    config.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        var settings = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RabbitMQSettings>>().Value;
        cfg.Host(settings.Host, "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username(settings.Username);
            h.Password(settings.Password);
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(settings.QueueName, e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false; 
            e.Bind<RequestReceived>(b =>
            {
                //in case of sharding
                b.ExchangeType = "x-modulus-hash";   
            });

            e.Consumer<MessageRequestConsumer>(); 
             
            cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ConsumerLoggingMiddleware<>), context); 
        }); 
    });
});

I would appreciate any kind of help or guidance, and please consider that I have never used this technology before.
